# Smart Sticky Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, navbar

I'm having a small problem with some text jumping around in my sticky menu. This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/u6ywraj8/

As you can see, I want the red `#menu` to stick to the top when a user scrolls down. However, the text in the top left part of the menu jumps around. I want this text to always be in the top left part of the red menu, I don't want it to have the initial ~100px padding.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
sticknav {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it says I need 15 reputation to vote up. As soon as I get it, I'll gladly upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: left;` to this class `sticknav{}`

```
sticknav {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Actually, now that I've tried it, there is one small error I'm finding. For some reason the top white header changes its height to 37px, but it is set to 30px. Please have another look if you have free time. Thank you!